# cfform cannot be initialized

Tags: coldfusion, http-status-code-404, cfform

I'm checking the tag cfform in coldfusion, the codes are very simple:

```
<cfform name="testFrm" format="Flash">
    <cfinput type="text" name="abc" value ="">
</cfform>
```

But when running it says: 
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - .../1405338045.mxml.cfswf"

The form cannot be shown.

Anybody here got this error? Could you help me about this, I have no any clues on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you do not have a /CFIDE virtual directory mapping, which one needs if one is to use things like `<cfform>`.

Short of having that mapping, one can use `<cfajaximport>` to specify an alternative location for the resource files that `<cfform>` requires to work.

Comment: Just a note, he is using Flash Forms, not JS/HTML forms, so cfajaximport won't help. But you are still right about it possibly being a CFIDE mapping issue. That being said, and this is not helpful to you, but just something to consider, I strongly urge you to NOT use Flash Forms. If you want to know why, reply and I'll expand on it, but, trust me, they aren't worth using.

Comment: Cheers for the correction there Ray.  Sorry to the OP for the bum-steer on that bit of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using CF11, open the web.xml file in

{CF11}\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\web.xml and uncomment any configs that have to do with SWF or CFForm. Restart CF and try again.

Had a client with lots of legacy code that needed flash forms and this fixed the 404's for "mxml.cfswf" files for the client, so I figured I'd post here for the sake of anyone else searching on this topic.